# SSRS 2016 Power BI Technical Preview

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2016

When trying to build a datset on the SSRS Power BI Technical Preview through the Report Builder 2016 I receive the hereunder error once I press save:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException: An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateDataSet(String dataSet, String parent, Boolean overwrite, Byte[] definition, Property[] properties, CatalogItem& itemInfo, Warning[]& warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateCatalogItem(String ItemType, String Name, String Parent, Boolean Overwrite, Byte[] Definition, Property[] Properties, CatalogItem& ItemInfo, Warning[]& Warnings)

I would appreciate any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the latest ddl for Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0

Comment: Thank you Bill for the helpful answer ... but, could you give me more information to solve the issue: 
- The link to download the DDL.
- Where exactly to save it [folder path].
- DDL Name. 
@Bill